# Flex: Syntax error before '=' token

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, flex-lexer

I am trying to build my own mini **C** language compiler using `flex` but there are an error that keeps showing up. Can you please help me to find what is the problem? I searched for a solution but still not found the reason behind this error. Here is the code:

```
%{
#define KEY_VOID = 258
#define KEY_FLOAT = 260
#define KEY_IF = 261
#define KEY_ELSE = 262
#define KEY_WHILE = 263
#define KEY_FOR = 264
#define KEY_RETURN = 265
#define KEY_BREAK = 266
#define AND_OP = 267
#define OR_OP = 268
#define SMALL_EQ_OP = 269
#define GREAT_EQ_OP = 270
#define EQ_OP = 271
#define SMALL_OP = 272
#define GREAT_OP = 273
#define NOT_EQ_OP = 274
#define ASSIGN_OP = 275
#define OPN_BRACKET = 276
#define CLS_BRACKET = 277
#define CLS_BRACE = 290
#define OPN_BRACE = 291
#define SEMICOLON_SYMBOL = 278
#define COMMA_SYMBOL = 279
#define DOT_SYMBOL = 280
#define ADD_OP = 281
#define SUB_OP = 282
#define ASTERISK_SYMBOL = 283
#define SLASH_SYMBOL = 284
#define START_COMMENT_SYMBOL = 285
#define END_COMMENT_SYMBOL = 286
#define INT_NUM 287
#define FLOAT_NUM 288
#define IDENTIFIER 289
Int  yylval;
%}
Letters     [a-zA-Z]
Digits      [0-9]
Sympols     [@#$%&*-+!"':;/?(),~`|^_=×{}<>]
%%
[/*][{Letters}|{Digits}|{Sympols}|\n|\t]*[/*]       {/* Ignore Comments */} 
[-+]?[{Digits}]+                        {yylval = atoi(yytext); return INT_NUM;}
[-+]?[{Digits}]+.[{Digits}]+                    {yylval = atoi(yytext);return FLOAT_NUM;}
[{Letters}][{Letters}|{Digits}|_]*              {return IDENTIFIER;}
[ \t\n]+                            {/* Ignore WhiteSpaces and New lines */}
"void"      {return KEY_VOID;}
"float"     {return KEY_FLOAT;}
"if"        {return KEY_IF;}
"else"      {return KEY_ELSE ;}
"while"     {return KEY_WHILE;}
"for"       {return KEY_FOR;}
"return"    {return KEY_RETURN;}
"break"     {return KEY_BREAK;}
"&&"        {return AND_OP;}
"||"        {return OR_OP;}
"<="        {return SMALL_EQ_OP;}
">="        {return GREAT_EQ_OP;}
"=="        {return EQ_OP;}
"<"     {return SMALL_OP;}
">"     {return GREAT_OP;}
"!="        {return NOT_EQ_OP;}
"="     {return ASSIGN_OP;}
"("     {return OPN_BRACKET;}
")"     {return CLS_BRACKET;}
";"     {return SEMICOLON_SYMBOL;}
","     {return COMMA_SYMBOL;}
"."     {return DOT_SYMBOL;}
"+"     {return ADD_OP;}
"-"     {return SUB_OP;}
"*"     {return ASTERISK_SYMBOL;}
"/"     {return SLASH_SYMBOL;}
.       {yyerror();}
%%

int main(void)
{
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int yyerror(void)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(1); 
}
```

And this is the error that keeps showing up:

> 46 C:\GnuWin32\GnuWin32\bin\Project.l syntax error before '=' token

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `#define`s - they should look just like:

```
#define KEY_VOID 258
```

But sometimes you have an extra equals sign there, for example:

```
#define KEY_VOID = 258
```

The error message line is misleading, because the error gets reported only where the macro is subsequently used, not where it is defined.

Comment: i traied your suggestion but i still have the same problem

Comment: Did you change it on all the `#define` lines?

Comment: OK, so there are some new errors - I tried it here myself and it's complaining about `Int yylval` (it would need to be lowercase `int`) and missing declarations for standard library functions like `malloc()` (you would need to add `#include <stdlib.h>` at the very beginning of the `%{` part). But even then you are missing the parser hooks which the lexer code calls with each symbol. You should have something like `#include "y.tab.h"` there, which declares those functions `yyerror()` and `yyparse()` and the variable `yylval` to interface with Bison parser or supply the same interface yourself.

Comment: i dont knw if this is the reason behind the problem but when compile the code in DevC++ the first line of the error says  C:\GnuWin32\GnuWin32\bin\Project.l In function `yylex':

Comment: You are missing one part of the story, the Yacc/Bison file called e.g. `Project.y`. You are supposed to call `yyparse()` from your `main()`, Bison-generated code then invokes `yylex()` generated by Flex whenever it needs to. If you don't want to use Bison, you need to supply that function yourself. See e.g. http://learn.yancyparedes.net/2013/03/writing-a-calculator-program-using-bison-and-flex/

Comment: it says that there are no "y.tab.h" file or directory i create a text file and name it y.tab.h but nothing changed and this is the only problem im facing know

Comment: thank you so much for helping me it works the only problem as you said is the yyparser and since i will not use bison i will try the link the you gave

Comment: If you don't want to use Bison, just call `yylex()` repeatedly from your `main()`.